# Javascript OnSnapshot listener for creation when document doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an application whichi allows users to signup using Google. We want to immediately retrieve the user document once the account is successfully created, but our cloud function for populating hte user document is triggered by `user.create`. I want the client to only retrieve the user document once it is created through the cloud function and avoid referencing documents which don't exist.
The solution I was thinking of was utilizing Firestore's `onSnapshot` function to be notified when the user document is created. I'm not sure whether onSnapshot can reference documents which don't exist, though, and if so whether I would receive an update callback when said document is created.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible to listen to a document that doesn't exist.  The listener will get called when it does first exist.  This is something that would be relatively easy for you to test on your own simply by writing a few lines of code to add the listener, then create the document in the console manually.  It doesn't matter how the document gets created.

I have written an entire [blog post](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-offload-client-work-to-cloud-functions-7c420710f07) on exactly this matter.